# Next.js TranspilePackages tries to resolve optional dependencies

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, package

I am using a local NPM package in my Next.js projects which has 'mongoose' as a dependency. In my next.config.js I have specified that my package should be transpiled:

`transpilePackages: ['my-package']`

'Mongoose' provides some optional functions that fall back on various dependencies like 'supports-color', 'kerberos', etc. But since I don't use these functions, I don't need these dependencies.

Why does Next.js still show me this error:

```
warn  - ../my-package/node_modules/debug/src/node.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'supports-color' in '/my-package/node_modules/debug/src'

Import trace for requested module:
../my-package/node_modules/debug/src/node.js
../my-package/node_modules/debug/src/index.js
../my-package/node_modules/mquery/lib/mquery.js
../my-package/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
../my-package/node_modules/mongoose/index.js

../my-package/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'kerberos' in '/my-package/node_modules/mongodb/lib'

Import trace for requested module:
../my-package/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
../my-package/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
../my-package/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
../my-package/node_modules/mongoose/index.js
```

I expect to see no error.